# Sandbox User iOS Email

Tags: testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, apple-id

I have read that the email address you use for sandbox tester creation doesn't have to be real, is that true?  Because I have made one with an email address that doesn't exist, and after I log in it wants me to verify the email address which I cant do because it's not real. Currently, if I run the app on my device with my real apple ID I get an empty array of products available which is a whole nother problem, but with my sandbox user the code doesn't even execute and I think that's because the email address hasn't been verified.

Answer (score 0):

I have just read some info from Apple on this and I yes it needs to be a real email address.

https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev8b997bee1